# Problem on Case Factorial Moment of Random Variables $\mathbb E \xi ^{k}$

Tags: real-analysis, probability-theory, random-variables, expected-value

Please here is a question am solving that I got stuck on the way.

**Question**: Let the random variable $\xi$ have finite $\mathbf E \xi ^{(k)}$ for all $k \in \mathbb N$. Prove that all $\mathbf E \xi ^{k}$ are also finite and defined uniquely by $(\mathbf E \xi ^{(k)}, k \in \mathbb N)$

**My Attempt:** Let write $\mathbf E \xi ^{(k)}$ in the form,
$\mathbf E \xi ^{(k)} = \mathbb E(\xi(\xi -1) \dots(\xi-\mathbf k +1))$
$=\mathbb E(\xi^k +a_1.\xi^{k-1}+\dots+a_{k-1}\xi)$

$=\mathbb E\xi^k + a_1.\mathbb E \xi^{k-1}+\dots+a_{k-1} \mathbb E \xi$

Where, $a_i$ are polynomials which are constant for fixed $k$.

For $k=1: \mathbb E \xi = \mathbb E^{(1)}=\mathbb E \xi$ is finite and can be uniquely defined by $\mathbb E ^{(1)}\xi$

For $k=2: \mathbb E \xi^{(2)+\mathbb E \xi}$  (we see that $\mathbb E \xi^2$ is also finite and can be uniquely defined by $\mathbb E^{(1)}$ and $\mathbb E \xi^{(2)}$).  Now I need to show by Induction that it holds for all $ k \in \mathbb N $.  **Please any assist or hint is highly appreciated. THANKS IN ADVANCE!**

Comment: I don't see any random graphs here. Do you just mean random variables?

Comment: @misha Yes the questions is on random variables. But am actually taking a course on random graph... Thanks

Comment: Since graphs don't appear in the problem, I'm going to re-tag your question so that it's more likely to show up for people who want to answer it. The solution to the problem will also not have any graph theory in it!

Comment: @MishaLavrov Oh that's nice, Thanks for that